# General way to express holomorphic function in terms of z?

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

For the holomorphic, complex-valued function f, defined as

$f(x + iy) = xy - x + y + i(-(1/2)x^2 + (1/2)y^2 - x - y + c)$

We can express this in terms of $z$ and $\bar z$  by substituting

$x = (1/2)(z + \bar z)$

and

$y = -i(1/2)(z - \bar z)$,

which puts f in the form

$f(z) = -i(1/2)z^2 - (1 + i)z + ic$, where we can see it does not depend on $\bar z$.

How is this substitution in particular chosen, and how would a valid/useful substitution be chosen for an arbitrary f?

Is there more than one possible substitution that could be performed in either this or the general case?

Answer (score 3):

If you already know that $f(x+iy)$ is holomorphic, which you can check using Cauchy-Riemann's equations, there is a nice, efficient trick to express $f$ in terms of $z$ (no $\bar z$ needed, the function is holomorphic!):

> Put $y=0$ and $x=z$. This gives you $f(z)$.

For your particular example:

\begin{align}
f(z+i0) &= z\cdot 0 - z + 0 + i(-(1/2)z^2 + (1/2)0^2 - z - 0 + c) \\
&= \frac{-i}{2} z^2 - (1+i)z + ic.
\end{align}

#### Why does this work?

Let $g(z)$ be the function constructed by the trick above. Then $g$ is holomorphic, and $g(x) = f(x)$ whenever $x$ is real (by construction). The identity theorem for holomorphic functions shows that $f = g$ everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

Functions in terms of the real or imaginary parts of a number are a broader set than those on the number itself. So as you might have guessed, there is no way to always eliminate the $\overline{z}$ from the equation. One example that shows this is f(x+iy)=x.

However, if having $\overline{z}$ is alright, you can always convert from x and y to z and $\overline{z}$. This is simply a reparameterization (you can think back to polar coordinates, when you converted from x and y to r and $\theta$)

Comment: Okay, thanks! Suppose that a substitution to eliminate $\bar z$ is possible - is there a systematic way to find it?

Comment: Keep in mind you can't "try to eliminate $\overline{z}$" -- either it is eliminated or not. This is because z and $\overline{z}$ are only related through the act of conjugation. It's not like there's some substitution that relates the two.